# Ошибка: java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.Integer

Tags: android, java

При нажатии на один из пунктов списка вылеазет ошибка: `java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.Integer` 
Не пойму как с ней бороться... вот весь код:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id){

            final SearchEngineInfo engine = (SearchEngineInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // ошибка в этой строчке
            if (engine.isGroup()) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(OnlineCatalog.this, EngineListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(OnlineCatalog.this.getIntent().getExtras());
                intent.putExtra(EngineListActivity.PARAM_GROUP, engine.getName());

                startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_SELECT_ENGINE);
            } else if (getCallingActivity() != null) {
                final Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(PARAM_ENGINE_NAME, engine.getName());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                OnlineCatalog.this.finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: А в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @VladD `
final SearchEngineInfo engine = (SearchEngineInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно потому, что long

```
public long getItemIdAtPosition (int position)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemIdAtPosition(int)
не может быть приведен к SearchEngineInfo
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Browser/com/android/browser/search/SearchEngineInfo.java.htm

Comment: ...ItemId..?